# jquery datatables selected row's data getting reset on paginated table while navigating on pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using jquery datatables . http://jsfiddle.net/s3j5pbj4/2/ 
I am populating around 3000 records in paginated table.Problem is that If am selecting few checkbox and dropdown options in first page and move to next page (by clicking on paginated next button) and again come back on first page , selected data is getting reset again (i.e. lets say every paginated page shows 10 rows on each page and if I have selected 5 rows on first page and then navigate to next page and again come back to first page selected row's data getting reset again). I want my user should be able to see what all selection he made on any page and then submit .

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
            var oTable = $('#dbResultsTable').dataTable({
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers" ,
                "paging":   true,
                "ordering" : true,
                "scrollY":false,
                "autoWidth": false,
                "serverSide": false,
                 "processing": false,
                  "bDeferRender": true,
                "info":     true ,
                "lengthMenu": [[10,25,50 ,100, -1], [10,25,50, 100, "All"]],
                "scrollX": "100%" ,
                 "aoColumns":[

            { "mDataProp": null},

            { "mDataProp": "operation"}
      ],

        "sAjaxSource" : "ResultPopulator",
        "bJQueryUI" : true,
        fnRowCallback : function(nRow,aaData, iDisplayIndex) {

        jQuery('td:eq(0)', nRow).html('<input id="checkId_' + nRow+ 'name="" type="checkbox")>');
        var operationString = '<select name="operation" >';

        operationString = operationString + '<option selected disabled hidden value=""></option>';
for ( var i = 0; i < aaData.operation.length; i++) {
operationString = operationString+ '<option>'   + aaData.operation[i]+ '</option>';
}

    operationString = operationString   + '</select>';
jQuery('td:eq(1)', nRow).html(operationString);
return nRow;
},
}
);
```

});

```
function validateFields(){
    var status = true;
     var rowSelected = false ;
      var rows = $("#dbResultsTable").dataTable().fnGetNodes();
        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            var cells = rows[i].cells;
            if(cells[0].children[0].checked){
                 rowSelected = true;
                 var operation =  cells[1].children[0].value;
                 if(operation==""){
                    var msz = " Please select an operation"  
                    status = false ;
                    printMsz(msz);
                     break;
                 }
            }
}
```

Can somebody help me on this ?

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: @DelightedD0D : thanks for your quick response, i am working on jsfiddle  will post jsfiddle link soon :)

Comment: @DelightedD0D : Here is the http://jsfiddle.net/s3j5pbj4/2/ link, just select any checkbox in first page , move to next page and come back to first page, selected row will be reset , no idea why

Comment: I guess  "fnDrawCallback": function() can be useful here but not sure how ,

Comment: Glad Gyrocode's solution worked for you. Additionally, If you're willing to build the table yourself then apply `dataTable()` the table will retain all selected input without any need to specially code for each element type, see http://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/s3j5pbj4/6/

Comment: @DelightedD0D : thanks but Building table at client side is not an option here , as data is huge so i just want to load it from server side(using ajax json data). In your example table state is getting retained because you DOM have complete data but in my case , table gets redraw  during every navigation so table state is not getting saved at client side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please take a look at [my solution at JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mbhn0nrL/2/).

**HTML**

```
<table id="test" class="display">
    <thead><tr><th>select</th><th>operation</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>

<p>
    <input id="test-data-json" name="test_data_json" type="hidden">
    <button id="btn-submit">Submit</button>
</p>
```

**Javascript:**

```
//ajax emulation
$.mockjax({
   url: '/test/0',
   responseTime: 200,
   responseText: {
      "aaData" : [
         [{"id":1}, {"chk":"on"}, {"operation":["Modify", "Delete"]}],
         [{"id":2}, {"chk":"on"}, {"operation":["Modify", "Delete"]}],
         [{"id":3}, {"chk":"on"}, {"operation":["Modify", "Delete"]}],
         [{"id":4}, {"chk":"on"}, {"operation":["Modify", "Delete"]}],
         [{"id":5}, {"chk":"on"}, {"operation":["Modify", "Delete"]}],
         [{"id":6}, {"chk":"on"}, {"operation":["Modify", "Delete"]}],
         [{"id":7}, {"chk":"on"}, {"operation":["Modify", "Delete"]}]
      ]
   }
});

// Global variable holding current state of the controls in the data table
var g_data = {};

var $table = $('#test');
$table.dataTable( {
   "lengthMenu": [[2,25,50 ,100, -1], [2,25,50, 100, "All"]],
   "pagingType": "full_numbers" ,
   "paging":   true,
   "ordering" : true,
   "scrollY":false,
   "autoWidth": false,
   "serverSide": false,
   "processing": false,
   "info":     true ,
   "deferRender": true,
   "processing": true,
   "columns": [
      ["data", 1 ],
      ["data", 2 ]
   ],
   "ajax" : {
      "url": "/test/0",
      "dataSrc" : function(json){
         var data = json.aaData;
         for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            var chk_name  = 'chk_' + data[i][0].id;

            // If checkbox was never checked
            if(typeof g_data[chk_name] === 'undefined'){
               // Retrieve checkbox state from received data
               g_data[chk_name] = (data[i][1].chk === 'on') ? true : false;
            }
         }

         return data;
      }
   },
   "createdRow" : function( row, data, index ){
      var chk_name  = 'chk_' + data[0].id;
      var chk_checked = (g_data[chk_name]) ? " checked" : "";

      $('td:eq(0)', row)
         .html('<input name="' + chk_name +'" type="checkbox" value="1"' + chk_checked + '>');

      var select_name = 'select_' + data[0].id;
      html =
         '<select name="' + select_name +'">'
          + '<option value="">Select one</option>'
          + '<option'
          + ((typeof g_data[select_name] !== 'undefined' && g_data[select_name] === data[2].operation[0]) ? ' selected' : '')
          + '>' + data[2].operation[0] + '</option>'
          + '<option'
          + ((typeof g_data[select_name] !== 'undefined' && g_data[select_name] === data[2].operation[1]) ? ' selected' : '')
          + '>' + data[2].operation[1] + '</option>';
          + '</select>';

      $('td:eq(1)', row).html(html);
   },
});

$('#test tbody').on('click', 'input[type=checkbox]', function (e){
   g_data[this.name] = this.checked;
});

$('#test tbody').on('change', 'select', function (e){
   if(this.selectedIndex != -1){
      var value = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
      g_data[this.name] = value;
   }
});

$('#btn-submit').on('click', function(){
   $('#test-data-json').val(JSON.stringify(g_data));
   console.log($('#test-data-json').val());
});
```

I have slightly updated your code since it was a mix of new and legacy options. However I haven't edited legacy server response using `aaData` property, so you don't have to change your server-side script.

Basically, the solution is to use a variable (`g_data` in my example) to store/retrieve state of dynamic form controls.

Upon form submission, the data is stored in hidden `INPUT` element as JSON string.

Optionally, if form validation is needed, inspect the state of controls stored in `g_data` variable.

Comment: Thanks a Million , you are a genius . Thanks for all your effort. Now with your permission i will use this code and extend it according to my requirement :) .

Comment: Thank you, glad that it worked for you. Although I'm not 100% sure whether it's the optimal solution.

Comment: today i figured out one more interesting thing, if you just replace  fnRowCallback : function() with "createRow":function()  (which you had used in your solution), there is no need to keep track of selected row's data :) . I was using fnRowCallBack function so it was re-drawing the table everytime on navigation but "createRow":function() gets called only once for every page navigation. We got so involved in issue didn't think solution would be so simple :) . But i really appreciate efforts  and solution you have given :).

Answer (score 1):

I solved this for you.
I recommend to you, to make 2 html files and 1 javascript file and insert my code (below) and play around a little with it. Check your Browsers console, because I added some console.log's so that you can see what is going on in detail.

Also THIS is a good read on the topic: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

In my example you have 2 html pages with 3 checkboxes each. Every time you switch between the checkboxes, the page gets reloaded (and all memory is lost). For this reason I added a little JavaScript file, that saves your checked checkboxes in the localStorage (a javascript object) of the users Browser.

Tell me if you still experience troubles.

HTML of PAGE 1:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test Page</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-1.16.0.css">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>

    <input type="checkbox" name="item_1">
    <label>Item #1</label>
    <br>

    <input type="checkbox" name="item_2">
    <label>Item #2</label>
    <br>

    <input type="checkbox" name="item_3">
    <label>Item #3</label>
    <br>

    <nav>
      <ul class="pagination">
        <li>
          <a href="#" aria-label="Previous">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="index.html">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="page2.html">2</a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" aria-label="Next">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="my_javascript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

HTML of PAGE 2:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test Page</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-1.16.0.css">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>

    <input type="checkbox" name="item_4">
    <label>Item #4</label>
    <br>

    <input type="checkbox" name="item_5">
    <label>Item #5</label>
    <br>

    <input type="checkbox" name="item_6">
    <label>Item #6</label>
    <br>

    <nav>
      <ul class="pagination">
        <li>
          <a href="#" aria-label="Previous">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="index.html">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="page2.html">2</a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" aria-label="Next">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="my_javascript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT from the embedded file "my_javascript.js"

```
$("input").click(function(){

    var key = $("input:hover").attr("name"); 
    var value = $("input:hover").attr("name");
    var item_is_present = false;

    console.log(key);
    console.log(value);

    if ( localStorage.getItem(key) != null ){
        localStorage.removeItem(key);
    } else {
        localStorage.setItem(key, value);
    };

    console.log(localStorage);
    console.log(localStorage.length);
});

$(function(){
    for ( var i = 0, len = localStorage.length; i < len; ++i ) {

        var myVar = localStorage.getItem( localStorage.key( i ) ) ;

        $("input[name=" + myVar + "]").prop("checked", true);
    }
});
```

Comment: This does not suit the OP's needs

Comment: @stylesenberg thanks for trying out but i guess you didn't get my question. In my case everytime if i click on next button table get re-draw and complete selected data of previous page get reset . If were to use localstorage 1) how efficient it will be , how much i can store here . I am pretty sure i am missing something here , surely datatables have this feature but not sure how to do that

Comment: @DelightedD0D : did you get a chance to look at my problem, i am struggling to find out what's wrong with my code :(

Comment: @hpppy18 localStorage may be very helpful in that matter. Not only can you save the users selections (in dropdowns & checkboxes) in the browsers localStorage, you can also refresh the data in the browser with this information (from localStorage). I really recomend you to try my answer's example and read about localStorage. IF however this may not help you, please provide me with more detailed information of what your problem is and how I can help you more. best regards.

Comment: localStorage capacity is about 5MB so you could really use that for your form (with dropdowns and checkboxes). br

Comment: @stylesenberg :I really appreciate you helping me out here. My problem is quite complex, In my actual table i have around 24 columns, columns types are ( checkbox, few select dropdown and one multiselect checkbox dropdown) . So I find it quite complex to implement , and ofcourse your option is cool but dont you think there should be simple way in datatables to retain the table state ?