# Codeigniter - jQuery Datatables Checked values from check boxes are not retained while searching and paginating

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, datatable

I am having an issue where in selecting multiple members from a jquery datatable from different pages, If I select 2 members from the first page and 2 from the second page, when I go back the the first page the values check boxes are not ticked and the same when I go back to the second page. Same thing happens while searching through the datatable. What could be the issue? I will post my Controller, Model, View, and Datatable JS below:

**VIEW:**

```
<div  class="col-md-12"><?php echo $this->table->generate(); ?></div>
```

**CONTROLLER:**

```
$tmpl = array ( 'table_open'  => '<table id="big_table" border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1" class="table table-striped">' );
$this->table->set_template($tmpl); 
$this->table->set_heading('<input type="checkbox" id="selAll" name="select_all" />','Customer Name','Email','Phone');
```

**MODEL:**

```
public function list_customers($center_id ='',$course_id =''){
$this->datatables->select("customer_id, CONCAT_WS( ' ' ,  firstname , lastname ) as firstname, email ,phone")->where('is_disable',0)
    ->edit_column('customer_id', input_checkbox('customer_id[]' ,'$1' ),'customer_id')->from($this->_table_name);

if(!empty($center_id)) $this->db->where('category',$center_id);
    if(!empty($course_id)){
        $this->db->where('customer_id IN (select customer_id from `dance_customer_course`  WHERE dance_customer_course.`festival_id` = '.$course_id.')');
    } 
    return $this->datatables->generate();
}
```

**DATATABLE (JS):**

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#sform").submit(function(){
            if($('.checkbox:checked').length < 1){
                alert("Please select the customer");
                return false
            }
            if($('#content').val() == ''){
                alert("Please enter content");
                return false
            }
        });

    var oTable = $('#big_table').dataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bInfo": false,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": '<?php echo base_url(); ?>sendsms/list_customers',
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "iDisplayStart ":20,
                "oLanguage": {
            "sProcessing": "<img src='<?php echo base_url(); ?>img/ajax-loader.gif'>"
        },  
        "fnInitComplete": function() {
                //oTable.fnAdjustColumnSizing();
         },
                'fnServerData': function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback)
            {
              $.ajax
              ({
                'dataType': 'json',
                'type'    : 'POST',
                'url'     : sSource,
                'data'    : aoData,
                'success' : fnCallback
              });
            }
        });




    $('#selAll').click(function(e){
        if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();

        var checkBoxes = $(".checkbox");
        if(checkBoxes.prop("checked")) $(this).text("Check All");
        else $(this).text("Uncheck All");
        checkBoxes.prop("checked", !checkBoxes.prop("checked"));
    });

    });
```

This is pretty much the code I have used, Can somebody please help me with this? Thank you.

Comment: check to google this "datatables mantain checked values throughout pages", a heap of hints pop-up

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery datatables selected row's data getting reset on paginated table while navigating on pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29057980/jquery-datatables-selected-rows-data-getting-reset-on-paginated-table-while-nav)

Comment: this answer has even a jsFiddle: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29063912/2275490

Comment: Thank you Vickel, I will look into these :)

Comment: Hi Vickel, The values get retained while `"bServerSide": false,` but it displays only 100 entries out of a possible 2000 entries

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
 $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
                                    newvalue = ( $(this).val());

                                    if (this.checked) {
                                        do your code
                                    }

do what you want

                                });
```

Comment: It should just retain the values on searching as well as going through different pages